# Sandbox and Saving files

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, sandbox, nssavepanel

I know about Sandbox limitations and and my usual technique of having the user save a file is via the `NSSavePanel`, which automagically grants the app the necessary priviliges to the location, as indicated by the user.

**Now, here's the... not-so-uncommon scenario :**

- User creates a new file, in my app
- Saves is for the first time (so, there's a good reason for the `NSSavePanel` to show up)
- Then edits the contents of the document (please, note that my app is *not* a typical `NSDocument`-compliant one)
- **And finally he want to re-save it**. (not "Save (it) as.." but just... "Save (it)" - since *he's already specified a location, right?*)

How is this doable? What's the "approved" way of achieving that? I've read about bookmarks but a) I'm not sure whether it is what I need, b) I haven't managed to find any real code example.

So, any ideas?

---

Please, note : no-matter-what, the solution must be fully-functional for 10.6 as well.

---

**UPDATE :** Hmm... That's just weird (or at least unexpected). Just tried re-saving at a previous location already selected via `NSSavePanel` and it seems to be working (without doing anything). Is that possible? (And yep, just re-checked it twice : the app *is* sandboxed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provided your own answer - “which automagically grants the app the necessary priviliges to the location, as indicated by the user” - when the user selects the file in the file panel the sandbox is *extended* to include the selected location and for the rest of the current execution your app my access it.

Comment: After 100 tests - more-or-less! lol - I verify it. Nothing more is needed. :-)